# Swift 3 subclassing uiviewcontroller created programmatically

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I have a slide in menu that I use to programmatically create a UIViewController:

```
func showControllerForMenu(_ menus: Menu) {
    let menuChoiceViewController = UIViewController()
    menuChoiceViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    menuChoiceViewController.navigationItem.title = menus.name
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =     [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(menuChoiceViewController, animated: true)
}
```

This works fine, what I'm trying to figure out is how to subclass the UIViewController in order to add controls and functionality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm unsure about your issue. If `menuChoiceViewController`, an *instance* of `UIViewController`, does what you need - why not simply *add* the subviews to it's main view? And if you wish to subclass it (which sounds like you may thinking correctly), why not simply subclass it and then instantiate the subclass? In other words, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm new to this so I may be asking the question incorrectly. I'm looking for a way to associate a .Swift file with the programmatically created UIViewController to put my code. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: If you are trying to have your `menuChoiceViewController` recognized as a view controller in IB, then you need to subclass it. I know of no other way to associate your code to something in IB.

Comment: I'm not using IB. I understand how to associate a class swift file in IB. I'm trying to figure out how to associate a .Swift file with a programmatically created UIView.

Comment: So, in your instance, how to rename `MainViewController.swift` to `menuChoiceViewController.swift`? If your `showControllerForMenu(menus:)` is a function within `MainViewController`, can you (1) declare `menuChoiceViewController at the `MainViewController` level, (2) create a new empty Swift file called `menuChoiceViewController.swift`, and (3) move this function into an extension to `MainViewController`? I feel I'm unclear on what you are trying to do. Sorry for that.

Comment: I decided to use xibs and their associated classes to achieve what I was looking to do. I wish I could've been a little more descriptive about my problem but I am just learning Swift and my programming abilities are a bit rusty.

Comment: Good luck! Sorry I wasn't able to help out much.